# What is the diamond mark printed in some mushafs in surah hud, verse 41?

Tags: reading-quran, tajweed

What exactly is the diamond mark printed in some mushafs in Surah Hud, verse 41, under the ra in "majrahaa"? Does this change the pronunciation?

[image]

Comment: You'll find the same mark in surat Yusuf http://legacy.quran.com/12/11 again, but this time with a different hukm of tajweed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This marks the only place in the *Hafs* reading of the Quran where *imala* is applied.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Im%C4%81la#section_2

In the *Hafs* reading, you don't pronounce the vowel in the middle of "majraha" as a regular *aliph*. Instead, you pronounce it like the letter "A" in "fate". You should find an audio sample of the *ayah* by a good *qari* to get it exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

This is called Imala, and the word in the Hafs reading that has Imala is the Ayah in your question.  It changes the"Fathah" a A sound to a "Kasra" a "e" or "i" sound, and it changes the "Alif" to a " Ya' ", so instead of saying "Majraha" you say "Majreha" or "Majriha".

You can hear it from a good reciter at [Qur'an Explorer](http://www.quranexplorer.com/Quran/Default.aspx), chose Abdul Basit as the reciter or the down from him.

Sources: [2](http://qurancomplex.org/quran/mostalhat.asp?TabID=1&SubItemID=8&l=arb&SecOrder=1&SubSecOrder=8#3)

Answer (score 0):

Majriha to be read majrayha(alquran Hud 11:41)
The right pronunciation version hafs the slang of an Arabic tribe(i=e but instead read it as ray ...maj ray ha) the only place in our holy quran being noted/marked with the diamond symbol(imala)
...in the name of Allah while the boat stoping or cruizing...Q11:41)..Allahuaklam